# Materialize date picker for select only month and year

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-material

I want to select month and year only in datepicker, but now it shows the date, once select the date, month and year only datepicker closed. But my format is 'mm-yyyy'.

I need the picker for month and year only without date in materialize or angular material not bootstrap.

Comment: Show some code how you are initializing date picker

Comment: $('#pickadate').pickadate({
          selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
          selectYears: 150, // Creates a dropdown of 150 years to control year
          format: 'mmm-yyyy',
          max: true,
          onSet: function (arg) {
            if ('select' in arg) { //prevent closing on selecting month/year
              this.close();
            }
          }